# Iron Router onBeforeAction isn't being called

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a `/user` route set up, which is supposed to render the `login` template if the current user isn't logged in. The entire router has a `waitOn` that waits for the `currentUser` subscription to finish. The problem is that when I go to `/user` it simply renders the `dataNotFound` template instead.

Here's the snippets of code that are relevant to this situation. I've been careful to show you them in the order they're defined in my `lib/router.js` file.

```
Router.plugin('dataNotFound', {notFoundTemplate: 'notFound'});

Router.onBeforeAction(function () {
    console.log(Meteor.userId())
    if (!Meteor.userId()) this.render('login');
    else this.next();
}, { only: ['user'] });

Router.configure({
    waitOn: function () { return Meteor.subscribe('currentUser'); }
});

Router.route('/user', {
    name: 'user',
    template: 'userView',
    data: function () { return Meteor.user(); }
});
```

That `console.log` above doesn't even ever fire. It seems to me that since it should be a reactive function that even if initially the `dataNotFound` is rendered, then soon after that the `onBeforeAction` should be fired and render the `login` template, right?

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with onBeforeAction hook after upgrading from meteor 0.9.1 to 1.
It didnt get fired when it should. Like after I log out, I enter address manually and instead of login page I can see the actual site waiting for data that never comes. onRun hook solved it, but as docs says it gets fired only once.

```
Router.onRun(function () {

    if (!Meteor.userId()) {
       this.render('login'); 
    } else { 
       this.next();
    }
}, { only: ['user'] });
```

Comment: Yeah it works the first time, but if the user logs out it's broken again. It's gotta be reactive :/

Answer (score 1):

It's very bizarre that your console log doesn't even fire. I have a few ideas, but first want to address the last piece of your question.

The dataNotFound plugin is triggered when the data function fires on your rout. This means it is bypassing your onBeforeAction hook altogether, and not that it isn't getting there.

One thing I can think of that might be worth trying would be wrapping the 'user' route action in a `if ( this.ready() )` statement:

edit:

`Router.route('user', {
    // Your other stuff
    action: function() {
        if this.ready() {
            this.render();
        },`

The reason I suggest this is just that you are using a waitOn statement, but I'm not 100% sure how that works if you don't have a this.ready() somewhere in your route, because that's what (again, from my reading of the documentation, have not fiddled around with it) tells the router what to wait before executing. Possibly it's not waiting at all right now.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I'm not sure what you mean by "wrapping the 'user' route"

Answer (score 0):

Try swapping out Meteor.userId() with Meteor.user() in your if statement. See this link for reference on how to handle checking for the user in a before filter: http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/meteorjs-iron-router-filters-before-and-after-hooks.

Comment: No effect I'm afraid :/

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue here.

According to this [post](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/1010#issuecomment-61630549), thanks to Steeve Cannon. The problem is on `waitOn` function.

Probably when you logginOut the subscribe to `currentUser` will fail, and this will make your app in infinite waiting. `onBeforeAction` runs after `waitOn`

You will need to check all variables in you Publish to insure waitOn complete successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Put an `if` statement inside the `waitOn` function.

```
waitOn: function () {
  if(Meteor.userId())
    return Meteor.subscribe('currentUser');
}
```

Refer this comment to know why this is happening: https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/1010#issuecomment-72210587