# Meteor Iron Router goes to a route's waitOn first instead of Router.onBeforeAction

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I've got the Meteor Roles package and I'm trying to define an admin route:

```
var requireLogin = function() {
  if (! Meteor.user()) {
    debugger // #1
    if (Meteor.loggingIn()) {
      this.render(this.loadingTemplate);
    } else {
      console.log("no user");
      this.render('AdminLogin');
    }
  } else {
    this.next();
  }
};

Router.onBeforeAction(requireLogin, {only: ['AdminMain']});

Router.route('/admin', {
  name: 'AdminMain',
  layoutTemplate: 'AdminLayout',
  waitOn: function(){
    debugger // #2
    return [
      Meteor.subscribe("appointments")
    ]  
  }
});
```

I've got this in server/publications:

```
Meteor.publish('appointments', function() {
  if (Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, ['assistant','admin'])) {
    return Appointments.find();
  } else {
    console.log("no user");
    return [];
  }
});
```

The ***first*** debugger that gets set off is debugger #2 in the `waitOn`. Why? I have an `OnBeforeAction` specified precisely for that route. According to the Iron Router guide, ***Our onBeforeAction hook function will run before our route function when the user navigates to "/admin". If the user is not logged in, the route function will never get called and the AdminPage will not render to the page.***

Well, it certainly looks like the route function is being called before the `OnBeforeAction` considering that debugger stops first to waitOn for a Meteor subscription. Since this subscription requires an admin user to be logged in on the server, if I press continue on debugger the server console logs "no user" and the loading screen goes on forever and forever. The actual `OnBeforeAction` function for `requireLogin` never gets called.

Comment: Refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36526134/1771949

Answer (score 0):

waitOn is called before OnBeforeAction. This behavious is corect. From the iron-router docs:

> Another alternative is to use waitOn instead of subscribe. This has the same effect but automatically short-circuits your route action and any before hooks (see below), and renders a loadingTemplate instead.

[Source](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#the-waiton-option)

For handling subscriptions you can use 'subscriptions' option:

```
Router.route('/post/:_id', {
  subscriptions: function() {
    // returning a subscription handle or an array of subscription handles
    // adds them to the wait list.
    return Meteor.subscribe('item', this.params._id);
  },

  action: function () {
    if (this.ready()) {
      this.render();
    } else {
      this.render('Loading');
    }
  }
});
```

[Source](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#the-subscriptions-option)